# Including Zii in Craft CMS

Tags: pagination

I have a large dataset of active records (not Craft entries) that I'd like to display in the admin frontend. Yii comes with a widget called CGridView, found here: `framework/zii/widgets/grid/CGridView.php`, which would fit the bill perfectly.

I've discovered that zii is not available in Craft, even though it's built on Yii. Is there an alternative to use in Craft that can provide a paginated grid view of active records or is there a way to include zii without affecting Craft core code?

This is for version 2.6 PRO of Craft CMS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Craft 2.x ships with a subset of the Yii framework files with things like zii and Yii widgets stripped out.

If you wanted to utilize them, you'd have to [create](http://pluginfactory.io) a [Craft plugin](http://craftcms.com/docs/plugins) and manually include the files that you're looking to use.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks Brad. At least it could be done without touching core. And thanks for the links, they're very helpful!